# OpenPGP: smart card / device not found on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gnupg, smartcard, openpgp

I'm trying to read my new GnuPG V3.3 smart card with OpenPGP on Windows 10, Lenovo keyboard with smart card reader, latest driver installed. When launching from CMD command `gpg.exe --card-status` getting this error:

```
gpg: selecting openpgp failed: No such device
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such device
```

PC was restarted, in device manager I can see that smart card reader driver is installed..

Answer (score 0):

After disabling at Device manager all other smart card drivers, except `Lenovo Keyboard Smartcard Reader`, smart card was found..